# python equivalent to procedure FACTMAC in SAS

Tags: python, sas, factors, factorization

Do python exist a package or implement equivalent to procedure FACTMAC SAS which can product k-dimensional feature factors for machine factorization?

Answer (score 0):

There are many open-source projects which implement Factorization Machines. Please refer to

https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM

https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/polylearn

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, these two implements can make a prediction or calcul rmse, but what i want are k features vectors.